# SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow gets canceled when I run it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

This is the choice field which customizes choice to drop down using jquery ,

[image]
SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow gets canceled when I run it. It's giving me this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: The value 'd/results(0)/Users'
>   cannot be read as type 'String'. at
>   Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.CheckedRead(String
>   propertyName, DynamicItem value) at
>   Microsoft.Activities.GetDynamicValueProperty`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say that "Users", since it's plural, implies a multi-user field, so it would be returning either a Collection of some sort (`string` user names? `int` user IDs?), or possibly another Dynamic Value, if it has more complex/full user objects.

Comment: We need more information. What does your workflow do? Is there a custom initiation form? What type of field is `Users`?

Comment: Its list form, type of users is choice. please check attachment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

to get a value of sharepoint group you need to declare it as Int.

Comment: Thank you for reply but Users type is choice not group.

Comment: what kind of users you have on your choice field?? single user or group of users??

Comment: users can be select multiple users based on check box please check attachment updated questions.

Comment: Thank you Milad .. I got answer, return type of users set Choices

Comment: Awesome to have it work :)